# Verify gumroad license using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Im trying to verify a license for my product using jquery post method. When I type in the below code I get this error

```
Failed to load https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried using the using postman and I get a success response.

Here's the piece of code i used

```
$.post('https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify', {product_permalink: "QPPED", license_key:"374655D6-5F404674-ACD67CA5-981BDFBD"}, 
    function(returnedData){
         console.log(returnedData);
});
```

and also the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o7g2qjky/39/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 1):

Based on gumroad api [doc](https://gumroad.com/api), It is not allowed to make gumroad license check request via the javascript.

Comment: it is possible by using PHP?

Comment: Yes it is possible with PHP

Comment: Please where I can start from? I'm working on a WordPress theme which is on PHP too and I don't have any idea how can I get started working with cURL with PHP!